# Creating shell script to compare files

Tags: shell, unix, testing

My goal is to create a shell script to compare to files and say that they failed if they are not the same. How does one do this? I have never written a shell script before.

Comment: It's hard to tell where you went wrong without seeing what you tried.

Comment: I have no idea where I begin, that's the problem. @l'L'l

Comment: You begin by trying something, failing, and trying again usually. There are lots of ways to compare files — what specifically do you need to compare? Please include that information in your question.

Comment: `diff -q file1 file2`

Comment: @kojiro, Don't forget the OP has said they don't know the basics, and also are looking to return `failed` as the response.

Comment: @l'L'l Among the most important things for a beginning programmer to learn is to distinguish the wheel they want to invent from the wheels that already exist. In this case OP did not say they wanted the literal string `"failed"` as a response, but by _say that they failed if they are not the same_ implied that any response clearly indicating that they are not the same, with a nonzero exit status, would be adequate. `diff -q` covers all this.

Comment: @kojiro, Good point, also `cmp file1 file2` would be my choice :)

Answer (score 0):

This is sample script to compare two files and output "SAME" or "NOT SAME".

```
cat cmptest.sh

#!/bin/sh
#
## Compare two files
if cmp -s $1 $2; then
  echo SAME.
else
  echo NOT SAME.
  exit 1
fi
```

How to use:

```
sh cmptest.sh file1 file2
```

If file1 and file2 are same, output "SAME".
If not, output "NOT SAME".